# Refreshing a window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in Tkinter and am wondering how to refresh a window, namely if I fill in a rectangle, I want the GUI to delete it a specified time later. How would I go about doing this? Documentation on Tkinter seems to be thin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Tkinter widget has a `after` method, which you can use to call your rectangle delete function e.g. in the example below first I change a msg using `after`, and then destruct the window using `after`

```
from Tkinter import *

def changeMsg():
    label.configure(text="I will self destruct in 2 secs")
    label.after(2000, root.destroy)

root = Tk()
mainContainer = Frame(root)
label = Label(mainContainer, text="")
label.configure(text="msg will change in 3 secs")
label.pack(side=LEFT, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
mainContainer.pack()
label.after(3000, changeMsg)
root.title("Timed event")
root.mainloop()
```